# How to auto generate id for child div in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

How to auto generate id for child div in JQuery. Please help me so can i solve problem.

there is html code i want to set ids for these so can i apply operation on these.

```
<div id="main">

<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

I want to fit this. when click on + it should be max on complete div and when less it should be again on same possition.

Comment: there are many ways for generating IDs. what is the markup and what have you tried?

Comment: show some markup, and javascript code, you tried?

Comment: You don't need ids to operate on those divs. What is it that you actually want to achieve? (There might be a better way.)

Comment: what `operation`you're trying to perform on child divs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you try to create new div and assign it to it one possible solution may be:

```
<div id="parent">

</div>

for(var i = 0; i< 10; i++) { // suppose I append 10 divs to parent
  $('#parent')
        .append('<div id="myid_'+ i +'">child'+ i +'</div>');
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/219/)**

But if you've already child `div`s  within parent then

```
<div id="parent">
  <div>child 1</div>
  <div>child 2</div>
  <div>child 3</div>
</div>
```

then one possible approach would be

```
$('#parent div').each(function(i) {
   $(this).attr('id', 'myid_' + i);
});
```

#### According to edit

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

 $('#main .child').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'myid_' + i);
 });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/217/)**

Another approach would be

```
$('#main .child').attr('id', function(i) {
   return 'myid_' + i;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/218/)**

Comment: @Pulkit I need some time, please wait

Comment: @Pulkit check this http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/238/.. here I tried to give you an example without generate random `id`s, you have to change CSS and some other as you expect

Comment: if there are multiple div how they will fit auto in main div. and how can i hide child div while a child is maximize.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ways to do it automatically because **live()** call does not support **ready** event

Answer (score 0):

This will give the child div's ID like `child-1`,`child-2` etc... child-n

```
$(function(){

   var childDivs=$("#main div");
   for(var i=0;i<childDivs.length;i++)
   {  
      $(childDivs[i]).attr("id","child-"+i);
   }        

});
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/nsQcR/12/
(You can check the view source to see the ID's);

Answer (score 0):

To follow on to thecodeparadox's response for creating new div and assigning values, if you'd like the `id` and other info to be taken from a hash within an array:

`arry = [{name: name1, addr: addr1, id: id1}, {name: name2, addr: addr2, id: id2}, etc...]`

```
<div id="parent">
</div>

for(var i = 0, l = arry.length; i < l; i++) {
  var obj = arry[i]
  name = obj.name
  pid = obj.pid
  addr = obj.addr
  $('#parent').append('<div id=' + pid + '>' + name + ': ' + addr + '</div>');
};
```